# How to plot graph in PyQt4 from the output result of the parsing log file wroten with python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt4, pyqtgraph

I have written with python a parsing file which contains the result of file.log which contains some data of my memory usage and cpu and time and what I want is to make the output result in graph of my PyQt4 interface instead of the terminal display.

This is my log file before parsing it:

```
Memory: svmem(total=4014465024, available=3451576320, percent=14.0, used=1240055808, free=2774409216, active=543842304, inactive=525877248, buffers=82866176, cached=594300928)
CPU: 35.70 %
Elapsed execution time: 0.642941951752 seconds
```

and this is my parsing file:

```
import re
class Parse(object):
    with open('./perf.log', 'r') as logFile:
        for line in logFile:
    
        # Searching for CPU metric
        cpu_search_result = re.search('CPU: ([0-9.]*) %', line)
        if cpu_search_result != None:
            cpu_metric = cpu_search_result.group(1)
    
        # Searching for Execution time metric
        execution_time_search_result = re.search('Elapsed execution time: ([0-9.]*) seconds', line)
        if execution_time_search_result != None:
            execution_time_metric = execution_time_search_result.group(1)
    
        # Searching for memory metric
        memory_search_result = re.search('\((.*?)\)', line)
        if memory_search_result != None:
            metrics_splited = memory_search_result.group(1).split(",")
            for pair in metrics_splited:
                splited_key_value = pair.split("=")
                metric_name = splited_key_value[0].strip()
                metric_value = splited_key_value[1].strip()
                memory_key_value_metrics[metric_name] = metric_value
    
    # --------- end - parsing the file ---------
    
    
    # --------- start - printing the result ---------
    
    # Print all memory metrics if they exist
    if (len(memory_key_value_metrics) > 0):
        print "memory metrics: "
        print "total = " + memory_key_value_metrics["total"]
        print "available = " + memory_key_value_metrics["available"]
        print "percent = " + memory_key_value_metrics["percent"]
        print "used = " + memory_key_value_metrics["used"]
        print "free = " + memory_key_value_metrics["free"]
        print "active = " + memory_key_value_metrics["active"]
        print "inactive = " + memory_key_value_metrics["inactive"]
        print "buffers = " + memory_key_value_metrics["buffers"]
        print "cached = " + memory_key_value_metrics["cached"]
    
    # Print CPU Metric
    if cpu_metric != -1:
        print "CPU = " + cpu_metric
    
    # Print Execution time metric
    if execution_time_metric != -1:
        print "Execution time = " + execution_time_metric
    
    # --------- end - printing the result ---------
```

I'm struggling to see where I have gone wrong, but then again I am somewhat new to Python.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? There is no plotting in your code.  SO is good for getting help with _specific_ questions / issues you are having.  Many people are willing to help with that however not many people are willing to write code from scratch for you.